# Ring whose proper ideals are finite is field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, integral-domain

> How can I prove that if I have a commutative ring $R$ with unity that is domain which all its proper ideals are finite then it is a field?

The only thing that I'm able to see is that $R$ is artinian and noetherian, but no more. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: Show that $\;R\;$ itself is finite, for example with a non-zero element $\;a\in R\;$, since $\;ar=ar'\implies a(r-r')=0\implies r=r'\;$ , Now use that any finite integral domain is a field.

Comment: I wanted to use the idea of finiteness, but I didn't find how to get that the ring is finite.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois I think DonAntonio's comment pointed this out. Suppose $R$ is not a field. Then there is $0\neq a\in R$ non-invertible. Therefore the ideal $I=aR$ is proper, hence finite. But the map $R\to aR$, $r\mapsto ar$ is bijective, so $R$ is finite.

Comment: Oooooh. I didn't saw that. Really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Artinian domain (with unity) is always a field - note that the ideals $ (a) \supset (a^2) \supset (a^3) \supset \ldots $ form a descending chain for nonzero $ a $, and being Artinian implies that we have $ (a^k) = (a^{k+1}) $ for some $ k $, so that $ x a^{k+1} = a^k $ for some $ x \in R $, thus $ xa^{k+1} - a^k = a^k (ax - 1) = 0 $. Now, since $ R $ is a domain we conclude that $ ax = 1 $, and $ x $ is the desired inverse.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be an integral domain whose proper ideals are finite. Assume that $R$ is not a field, Then $R$ has a nonzero maximal ideal $M\lhd R$, and we may choose $a\in M-\{0\}$. The ideal $M$ contains all powers $a, a^2, a^3,\ldots$, so by finiteness we must have $a^m=a^{m+k}$ for some positive $m$ and $k$. Choose positive $\ell$ so that $m+\ell$ is a multiple of $k$. Then for $e=a^{m+\ell}$ we have $e^2 = e\in M$.

Now $R$ is a domain and $a\neq 0$, so $e = a^{m+\ell}\neq 0$. Since $0 = e^2-e = e(e-1)$, we derive that $e=1$, again using that $R$ is a domain. But now we have $1 = e\in M$, a contradiction.

Comment: If the *definition* of integral domain includes only rings with unit $\;1\;$ this is fine, otherwise you'd have first to prove it has a unit element.

Comment: The question specifies that $ R $ has unity.